# Throttle method in C#

Tags: c#, api, httprequest, throttling

I have method that make request to some 3rd party API and return response from it.
As this API allows only 50 calls per 1 minute, I want to throttle my requests to this API.

Currently I'm thinking of using Polly and add something like wrapper to my code

```
var policy = Policy.Handle<HttpRequestException>()
                   .WaitAndRetryForever(retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

var response = await policy.ExecuteAsync(async () => await DoApiCallAsync()
                           .ConfigureAwait(false));

return response;
```

But maybe here is better way of doing this.

Comment: Does your current code work? If so, https://codereview.stackexchange.com may be more appropriate. If it doesn't work, you need to be explicit about what doesn't work.

Comment: In general: `WaitAndRetryForever` sounds dangerous.

Comment: @Stefan, well yes, maybe here it will be enought 3 times at least...

Answer (score 2):

`Polly` is good, we use it in our infrastructure for retry mechanism between our microservices, but then I do not recommend `.WaitAndRetryForever`, since it really sounds dangerous like @Stefan said. What happens if 3rd party API goes in 30 minutes maintenance/downtime/unresponsiveness I know it does not happen very often but still.

I will suggest using `Polly` for overcomming issues with network. For instance possible network down times of the 3rd party API, but not about throttling.

About throttling I would suggest creating some [queue based](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/queue-based-load-leveling) pattern where you store your requests and process them with a given rate.

Sadly this have two more drawbacks:

1. You will need to implement some logic on your end in order this queue not to become really big and make your process consume a lot of memory.
2. It might be bad user experience if someone is waiting more than certain amount of time in order to receive their response.

Since I don't know the nature of your API this is as far as I can go with the suggestions, you have to decide if this suits for you. Good luck!

**Note:** `.waitAndRetryForever` is not so bad if you are using it for internal communication and you want to loosen your [service-level agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service-level_agreement). (You don't want your whole infrastructure to fall just because one service died for instance).

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to have control over everything (customize it as you want)

You can also scale workers to make multiple requests in parallel

Example

```
Worker worker = new Worker();
worker.OnRetry += (id) =>
{
  //called when error occurs
  //here you can wait as you want and send next request
};
worker.OnRespnse += (sender, success) =>
{
  //called on response
  //customize success depend on response status-code/body
  //here you can wait as you want and send next request
};
worker.Start("request body");
//you can start this worker over and over
```

Worker Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace app
{
    class Worker
    {

        public delegate void OnRetryDelegate(int id);

        public event OnRetryDelegate OnRetry;

        public delegate void OnRespnseDelegate(Worker sender, bool success);

        public event OnRespnseDelegate OnRespnse;

        public Worker()
        {
            Id = IdProvider.GetNewId();
            thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ExecuteAsync));
            thread.Start();
        }

        private readonly Thread thread;
        public string Number;
        public bool Idle { get; set; }
        public bool ShutDown { get; set; }
        public bool Started { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; private set; }
        public PostData { get; set; }

        public void Start(string postData)
        {
            PostData = postData;
            Idle = true;
            Started = true;
        }

        private void ExecuteAsync()
        {
            while (!ShutDown)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1500);
                if (Idle)
                {
                    Idle = false;
                    if (Number == "terminate")
                    {
                        ShutDown = true;
                        return;
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("https://example.com");
                        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
                        Debug.Print("send:  " + postData);
                        request.Method = "POST";
                        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
                        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                        {
                            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                        }
                        var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
                        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                        Debug.Print(responseString);
                        if (responseString.Contains("something"))
                            OnRespnse?.Invoke(this, true);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        OnRetry?.Invoke(Id);
                    }

                    OnRespnse?.Invoke(this, false);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```